# Is a user defined function able to act instead of libc's function ?

Tags: c, linux

I want to code some libc functions myself (but not all libc!) for increasing performance in my programs . but does GCC use them instead of libc functions in the compiled program or ignores them?

Comment: Check out "weak linking" or "weak symbols" in the GCC manual. Or just LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: *for increasing performance in my programs* If you have to ask this question, libc is probably not a performance bottleneck.

Comment: You do have an ego that thinks that you can improve performance with libc functions compared to the rest of us that has used it without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all the public symbols in glibc are [weak linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol), which means you can provide your own implementation which will take precedence over the weak symbols during linking.

So, yes. You can just define your own functions with the same name/arguments and they will get used instead. Be sure to look in the header files to see the real signature of a function, some functions may be a macro expanding to another function.

You can also create a shared library that contains the functions you want to override, and have the dynamic linker pre-load it to override functions in shared libraries. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) for more information.